# How to play a docker run --rm with docker-java?

Tags: java, docker, ffmpeg, docker-java

In our J2EE project, we want to call [sjourdan/ffmpeg](https://hub.docker.com/r/sjourdan/ffmpeg/) docker through the [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) library.

A typical call for ffmpeg conversion will be something like:

```
docker run --rm -v /e/data:/tmp/workdir sjourdan/ffmpeg -i /tmp/workdir/test.mov -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac /tmp/workdir/test.mp4
```

We managed all of that with a `DockerClient.createContainerCmd()` and the right `.with()` methods, except for  the `--rm` argument.

Is there a way to add it through docker-java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this other StackOverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28468828/923712), `--rm` is not handled by the Docker API, so we got no luck with docker-java either.

So, in the end we carefully remove the container after the execution, something like:

```
dockerClient.startContainerCmd(container.getId()).exec();
// do some stuff
dockerClient.removeContainerCmd(container.getId()).withForce(true).exec();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can send "AutoRemove" value to docker API:

```
String containerId = dockerClient.createContainerCmd(image).
    withHostConfig(new HostConfig() {
        @JsonProperty("AutoRemove")
        public boolean autoRemove = true;
    }).exec().getId();
dockerClient.startContainerCmd(containerId).exec();
```

That's it

Docker API info https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/ContainerCreate

"AutoRemove" was accepted, at least, starting at v1.25

Comment: Didn't work for me. Spring Boot 2.3; docker-java 3.2.3.

Comment: @RafaelS.Fijalkowski In case you still need it, it is possible for `docker-java:3.2.8`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the current version, which is `3.2.8`, you can set the autoremove option with:

```
dockerClient.createContainerCmd(image).withHostConfig(new HostConfig().withAutoRemove(true)).exec()
```